# Tab to next control from within the datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, tabbing

The use of tab keys within the WPF datagrid is my big issue these days. Oh, the datagrid. Why does it behave like it does anyway... :S

1st: I want to disable the ability to use the tab key within the datagrid. Once the focus is set within the datagrid I want to use the arrow keys to navigate.

2nd: If the user hits the tab key within the datagrid I want to jump out of the datagrid and get focus of the next element after the datagrid in the correct tab order.

Any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I would discourage you from doing that, tabbing through cells is a functionality some users might expect, changing that behaviour might irritate them.

Comment: Well, in the business app we are creating the functionality is a common user interaction. So we actually need to do what I described above. This is an expert application and the users have very large datagrid. However, they mostly use the keyboard to navigate between the controls around the datagrid as well. So this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: By the way, you can use `Ctrl+Tab` to tab out of it.

Comment: @H.B. `Ctrl+Tab` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the KeyUp or PreviewKeyUp event, listen for a tab and respond accordingly.